# Elasticsearch index a file automatically

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch,this question might look weird but is it possible to index a file automatically (i.e given a file path, elasticsearch should index the contents of it automatically).I have got some open source tool like elasticdump and tried using it for the purpose,but I prefer some plugins of elasticsearch which can support almost all elasticsearch versions.. Can anyone suggest me?

Comment: Try to be more specific about which approaches you have already tried. Broad questions like this are generally frowned upon on stackoverflow .

Comment: I have written that I already tried using elasticdump...But as it is not an elasticsearch plugin I wanted to know if any plugin of elasticsearch is available